# Find a particular element in List<> and fetch whole data of that row if element is found

Tags: c#

I have a `List<>` which contains collection of objects after getting this list of `BillSheetDetail` I want to find that `billWorkDetails[].details_classification =="xyz"` and if it is found then fetch all the data of that particular array index of `billWorksDetails[]` and store it in other array to display.

How can I do this? I am new to C#

```
public class BillSheetDetail
{
    public DateTime creation_date { get; set; }
    public string customer_name { get; set; }
    public string subject { get; set; }
    public decimal tax_rate { get; set; }
    public int total_amount { get; set; }
    public string special_instruction { get; set; }
    public string comment { get; set; }
   public  List<BillWorkDetail> billWorkDetails { get; set; }
}
[Serializable]
public class BillWorkDetail
{
    public string product_name { get; set; }
    public decimal quantity { get; set; }
    public string unit { get; set; }
    public int unit_cost { get; set; }
    public int amount { get; set; }
    public string remarks { get; set; }
    public int row_no { get; set; }
    public string details_classifiction { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: It's a `List<BillWorkDetail>` not an array.

Comment: you can use linq query and apply where clause

Comment: Sorry It is a List<BillWorkDetail>.I am not much aware of linq . will be grateful if someone explain me with some code.

Answer (score 1):

You have to combine `Enumerable.Where` and `Any`.

```
List<BillWorkDetail>[] matchingSheetDetails = billSheetDetailList
    .Where(sd => sd.billWorkDetails.Any(d => d.details_classifiction == "xyz"))
    .Select(sd => sd.billWorkDetails)
    .ToArray();
```

This creates an array of all matching lists. Since your question is unclear, if you actually only want an array of the matching `BillWorkDetail` objects:

```
BillWorkDetail[] matchingBillWorkDetails = billSheetDetailList
    .SelectMany(sd => sd.billWorkDetails.Where(d => d.details_classifiction == "xyz"))
    .ToArray();
```

`SelectMany` selects all matching `BillWorkDetail` out of the `List<BillSheetDetail>`. Note that both approaches lose the reference to the `BillSheetDetail` instance from where it came from.

Comment: Thanks @Tim it worked for me .Sorry about my unclear question actually I wanted it in List<> format. I edited your code with ToList() method and it worked.

Comment: Accepting it as an answer would be appreciable

Answer (score 0):

The solution is using the *Where* clause:

```
mySheetDetail.billWorkDetails.Where(x => x.details_classification == "xyz").ToList();
```

Here is a demonstration of the code that is working well: http://ideone.com/s2cUaR

Comment: This wouldn't work, you cant access a property from a list of items... See Tim Schmelter's answer for correct solution

Comment: No I don't _details_classification_ is a string. Look at the definition.

Comment: `mySheetDetail` is a `List<BillSheetDetail>` and you try to access a single property  from a list

Answer (score -1):

Try this linq method

```
List<BillWorkDetail> myBillWorkDetails = new Lis<BillWorkDetail>();

myBillWorkDetails  = myBillSheetDetail.billWorkDetails.Where(b => b.classifiction == "xyz").ToList();
```

This code retrieve all BillWorkDetail with classification xyz.